# hostapd will not start via "service" -- but will start directly

Tags: networking, services, init-script, init.d, hostapd

I am having trouble getting `hostapd` to start as a service.  It fails when I try to start it:

```
$ sudo service hostapd start
[FAIL] Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapd failed!
```

From what I understand, this uses the configuration in `/etc/default/hostapd`:

```
$ cat /etc/default/hostapd 
# Defaults for hostapd initscript
#
# See /usr/share/doc/hostapd/README.Debian for information about alternative
# methods of managing hostapd.
#
# Uncomment and set DAEMON_CONF to the absolute path of a hostapd configuration
# file and hostapd will be started during system boot. An example configuration
# file can be found at /usr/share/doc/hostapd/examples/hostapd.conf.gz
#
#DAEMON_CONF=""
DAEMON_CONF=”/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf”

# Additional daemon options to be appended to hostapd command:-
#   -d   show more debug messages (-dd for even more)
#   -K   include key data in debug messages
#   -t   include timestamps in some debug messages
#
# Note that -B (daemon mode) and -P (pidfile) options are automatically
# configured by the init.d script and must not be added to DAEMON_OPTS.
#
DAEMON_OPTS="-d"
```

My daemon configuration file is as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
driver=rtl871xdrv
country_code=USA
ctrl_interface=wlan0
ctrl_interface_group=0
ssid=KITT
hw_mode=g
channel=1
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=georgeisyourfriend
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
beacon_int=100
auth_algs=3
macaddr_acl=0
wmm_enabled=1
eap_reauth_period=360000000
```

Despite the service failing to start, I am able to start it directly on my own without error:

```
$ sudo hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
ctrl_interface_group=0
drv->ifindex=3
Configure bridge br0 for EAPOL traffic.
BSS count 1, BSSID mask 00:00:00:00:00:00 (0 bits)
Completing interface initialization
Mode: IEEE 802.11g  Channel: 1  Frequency: 2412 MHz
RATE[0] rate=10 flags=0x1
RATE[1] rate=20 flags=0x1
RATE[2] rate=55 flags=0x1
RATE[3] rate=110 flags=0x1
RATE[4] rate=60 flags=0x0
RATE[5] rate=90 flags=0x0
RATE[6] rate=120 flags=0x0
RATE[7] rate=180 flags=0x0
RATE[8] rate=240 flags=0x0
RATE[9] rate=360 flags=0x0
RATE[10] rate=480 flags=0x0
RATE[11] rate=540 flags=0x0
Flushing old station entries
Deauthenticate all stations
+rtl871x_sta_deauth_ops, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff is deauth, reason=2
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_key_ops
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr 80:1f:02:d3:cb:b8 and ssid 'KITT'
Deriving WPA PSK based on passphrase
SSID - hexdump_ascii(len=4):
     4b 49 54 54                                       KITT
PSK (ASCII passphrase) - hexdump_ascii(len=18): [REMOVED]
PSK (from passphrase) - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
rtl871x_set_wps_assoc_resp_ie
rtl871x_set_wps_beacon_ie
rtl871x_set_wps_probe_resp_ie
urandom: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/urandom
GMK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
Key Counter - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
WPA: group state machine entering state GTK_INIT (VLAN-ID 0)
GTK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
WPA: group state machine entering state SETKEYSDONE (VLAN-ID 0)
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_beacon_ops
rtl871x_set_hidden_ssid ignore_broadcast_ssid:0, KITT,4
rtl871x_set_acl
wlan0: Setup of interface done.
```

Comment: If you are having issues getting `hostapd` to run via `init.d` (`service hostapd start`) and nothing seems to be occurring... refer to this [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1495554).

Answer (score 15):

All what you have to do is to write this command:

```
sudo hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

it will list you all errors, you can then correct them in `hostapd.conf` file

```
sudo nano /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Answer (score 14):

you have to configure:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/hostapd

DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

Find the line above and tell the defaul config where your one is.

Answer (score 11):

This was a problem for me also and obviously still exists. 
I fixed the errors by removing hostapd from */etc/rc2.d/* and */etc/networking/if-pre-up.d/*

/etc/network/interfaces controls hostapd now..

```
iface wlan0 inet static
         post-up /usr/sbin/hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
         post-up service isc-dhcp-server restart
         address 192.168.10.1
         netmask 255.255.255.0
```

A reboot confirmed it brings up the interface; and Stations connect fine.
Previously I had to ssh in and stop *isc* and *hostapd* and do what the **post-up** now does (in that order)

Comment: @lordvlad is more correct, I had missed the DAEMON_CONF setting, which is why the -B option worked for me.

Comment: 'Correct' is what works, and this one works on systemd, neatly sidestepping a bunch of other issues the others don't solve.

Comment: @Teoma, actually @lordvlad is incorrect if you follow typical hostapd instructions and set DAEMON_CONF in `/etc/defaults/hostapd` as @Matt (not me) suggests in another answer (rather than hackily putting it in `/etc/init.d/hostapd` as vlad suggests). That said, your particular answer here addresses a race condition that exists even after that DAEMON_CONF is set, which is more of a bug in how hostapd's startup scripts are implemented than anything. So, thank you for that!!

Comment: This is the only way I could get it to work on raspbian, rpi3. And that with >15 years unix experience. Systemd hijacked `start-stop-daemon` and does a crappy job at starting a sysv daemon (both udhcpd and hostapd). I have no clue what could be wrong, cause as far as systemd goes it did it's job (and the daemon "exited"). So if you have post-up, use it.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem. By default install on my raspian wheezy, hostapd is started as S01 in services. This makes it start before `ifplugd` which configures eth0 and wlan0. The reason for this is that `S01h[ostapd]` < `S01i[fplugd]` since scripts are sorted in alphabetical order for execution.

I think that the bridge gets a hard time getting configured before everything else. Moving it to S05 didn't help either so I moved it to rc.local instead, which gets executed "a while" after everything else. I also removed all links from rc[2-5].d to `hostapd`. I think that S05 is still too soon for dhclient to finish properly. I am not sure this is according to the best practices. What seems to happen now is that ifplugd fails to bring `br0` up but `eth0` is more cooperative. I am not sure why wpa_supplicant fails here, probably because `wlan0` is already promised to `br0`. It needs to be disabled anyway. Later on, hostapd tries to bring `br0` up again and succeeds since `eth0` is ok and no one took control of `wlan0`.

There is another possible configuration where you could specify a `post-up`/`pre-down` option for `br0` in `/etc/network/interfaces` (man interfaces). You could start/stop `hostapd` from there. I didn't manage to get it to work however, but this looks like a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with your quotes on line 11 of `/etc/default/hostapd`:

```
”/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf”
```

Which should read:

```
"/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

Your post actually helped me solve my problem, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding 10 seconds sleep in file `/etc/init.d/hostapd` fixed the problem for me.

1) `sudo nano /etc/init.d/hostapd`
2) Add the `sleep` in `start)` section like below

```
case "$1" in
  start)
        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
        sleep 10
        start-stop-daemon --start --oknodo --quiet --exec "$DAEMON_SBIN" \
                --pidfile "$PIDFILE" -- $DAEMON_OPTS >/dev/null
        log_end_msg "$?"
        ;;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `DAEMON_CONF` in `/etc/init.d/hostpad`.

It's really quite obvious if you look into `/etc/init.d/hostapd`,
the default looks like this:

```
...
14 PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
15 DAEMON_SBIN=/usr/sbin/hostapd
16 DAEMON_DEFS=/etc/default/hostapd
17 DAEMON_CONF=
18 NAME=hostapd
19 DESC="advanced IEEE 802.11 management"
20 PIDFILE=/var/run/hostapd.pid
21
22 [ -x "$DAEMON_SBIN" ] || exit 0
23 [ -s "$DAEMON_DEFS" ] && . /etc/default/hostapd
24 [ -n "$DAEMON_CONF" ] || exit 0
...
```

because `DAEMON_CONF` is empty to start with, the script exits at line 24. Too bad there is no error message or anything. Changing line 17 to

```
 DAEMON_CONF=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

and putting the configuration in the specified file worked for me.

Comment: If one has followed the typical installation instructions for hostapd, this answer is incorrect and likely to confuse. Line 23 pulls variables defined in the file referenced by DAEMON_DEFS, which in turn typically has DAEMON_CONF defined in it. Thus, this script will only exit at line 24 if DAEMON_CONF is defined in neither `/etc/init.d/hostapd` (which you've misspelled as hostPAD in your first line) nor `/etc/defaults/hostapd`.

Answer (score 0):

On Arch linux, where systemd seems the norm over rc/init.d I had a similar problem. This answer differs from the others in the following ways :

1. The configuration file does not reside in `/etc/init.d` but somewhere under `/etc/systemd/system/`. Specifically `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/hostapd`, in my case, where the `ExecStart` line points to the configuration file used.
2. Importantly this configuration file also points to the binary used, namely `/usr/bin/hostapd`.

The fix is then to check which hostapd file you are actually executing. running `whereis` will tell you what versions are available and where they are located. So

```
whereis hostapd
```

produces something like

```
/sbin/hostapd /usr/bin/hostapd /usr/local/bin/hostapd
```

Testing each one by systematically calling `PATH/hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` for each `PATH` identifies which one you're actually invoking and which one systemd is invoking. Again in my case the last path is what I was invoking when I punched in `sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`. The second one is what systemd was invoking.

The trick is to copy the binary from `/usr/bin/local` to `/usr/bin` or to point systemd to the working hostapd. I believe the former is the "safer" option.

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/hostapd /usr/bin hostapd.bkp     # delete later as necessary
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/hostapd /usr/bin
```

Again in my case the binary under `/usr/bin/local` came from compiling the Realtek driver from source off of their [website](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) as described [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=25921).
Well done to Realtek for supporting Linux.

Hope this helps, is not specific to my system (Arch (Arm) Linux on a Raspberry Pi B) and qualifies as a suitable answer according to the UE rules.